# Using the Google API javascript in Cordova / Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-drive-api, phonegap-plugins, google-signin

I'm developing an application with Cordova and would like to save files in Googe Drive.

I've got success in login to Google, using the cordova-plugin-googleplus (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus). However I could not get the plugin returns to me accessToken or idToken so I could use with Google javascript API.

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login(
    {
        'scopes': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file profile',
        'offline': true, 
        'webApiKey': ‘CODE’ 
    },
    function (obj) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.srcImage = obj.imageUrl;
            $scope.NomeGoogle = obj.displayName;
        });
    },
    function (msg) {
        alert('Erro');
        alert('error: ' + msg);
    }
);
```

I tried using the code below, but returned me the following error:

> "Uncaught gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy"

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {

    gapi.auth2.init({

        client_id: 'REVERSED_CLIENTID',

    }).then(function(){

        auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get()); //now this always returns correctly        

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem, why wasn´t getting the serverAuthCode from plugin.
It is necessary to create 2 credentials on the Google Developers Console. The 1st must be Android, this will be for the plugin and the 2nd should be a Web App, this is necessary to achieve serverAuthCode.

The code looks like this

```
window.plugins.googleplus.login(
    {
        'scopes': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file profile',
        'offline': true, 
        'webApiKey': ‘REVERSED_CODE of Web App Credential’ 
    },
    function (obj) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.srcImage = obj.imageUrl;
            $scope.NomeGoogle = obj.displayName;
        });


            var data = $.param({
                client_id: 'REVERSED_CODE of Web App Credential',
                client_secret: 'SECRET_CODE of Web App Credential',
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                code: obj.serverAuthCode
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", data, config).success(function(data, status) {
                //data.access_token;

/** from now you can do use of google API **/

            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
            });

    },
    function (msg) {
        alert('Erro');
        alert('error: ' + msg);
    }
);
```

Thank you for your reply rojobo

Comment: What should I do in angular2 with typescript? $.param is Jquery method but angular2 doesn't support Jquery?

Answer (score 2):

At first I was hoping to skip the need for cordova-plugin-googleplus and just use the `gapi` within Cordova/PhoneGap to handle authentication with Google, but it appears the [gapi client authentication may not work within cordova's `file://` protocol](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin/issues/82#issuecomment-148276184).

The [answer from @Joao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36987693/763010) sent me in the right direction, but I kept getting the `Invalid cookiePolicy` error when trying to use the `gapi` after retrieving the `access_token` (this was because I was ignoring step #2 listed below, and after authenticating with the plugini I was mistakenly trying to authenticate *again* with the `gapi`).

There is a step (#3 mentioned below) that was unclear to me. To authenticate with Google and then use the `gapi` in Cordova/PhoneGap, this worked instead...

1. use the [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) to take care of the authentication and access token retrieval, do not use the gapi at all here
2. load the gapi client library (skip over the `gapi.client.init()` call and all the normal gapi authentication procedures)
3. Attach the access token we got from the plugin to the gapi client, and then make your gapi calls as needed

Step #3 took [some digging for me to find](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/304#issuecomment-307655705), and meant I needed to add the `access_token`

```
gapi.client.setToken({access_token:'abc123456xyz'});
```

Once the access token was attached to the gapi client, I could use the gapi within Cordova/Phonegap:

```
// Load the YouTube API.
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
  // Do stuff...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    window.plugins.googleplus.login(
        {
            'scopes': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file profile',
            'offline': true, 
            'cookiepolicy': 'none',
            'webApiKey': ‘CODE’ 
        }
```